# How do I construct a click event from fixed part into a dynamic/variable part? (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple CSS3 Flipbox which I'm trying to re-use multiple times. The best would be if each element has a unique ID, and each of them would be separately triggered on click.

At the moment all the elements are being triggered on click.

What would be the best approach without just doubling the code?

Here demo of the code:

https://codepen.io/baidoc/pen/LYeqwxe

```
let cardTransitionTime = 500;

let $card = $('.card');
let switching = false;

$('.card').click(flipCard);

function flipCard() {
  if (switching) {
    return false;
  }
  switching = true;

  $card.toggleClass('is-switched');
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $card.children().children().toggleClass('is-active');
    switching = false;
  }, cardTransitionTime / 2);
}
```

Comment: Pass the ID of the card that you want to flip to the flipcard function?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would be for one element, what if I want to do it for multiple ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent thought your transitionTime example through and left it out in a more simplified example, but for the other part you can simply use the event argument which is handed over to your called function per default:

```
$('.card').click(flipCard);

function flipCard(ev) {
  ev.currentTarget.classList.toggle('is-switched');
}
```

Comment: This is really great and simple. How would I approach the function "flipCard" if I would want to use a different selector? Reason being, that I want the toggle to happen in a different class, not "currentTarget"

Comment: function flipCard() {
      $('.different-class').classList.toggle('is-switched');
}

won't work

Comment: @Tudor you bind that event to a different class, with `$('.different-class').click(flipCard);`, `document.getElementById('idOfObject').click(flipCard);` or `const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("different-class");` --> `for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) { collection[i].click(flipCard); }`, for example

Comment: your help is much appreciated, thank you, however, the issue that I'm having, is that I want the trigger (toggle) of the card to be another class. Take a look here, so you get the idea: https://jsfiddle.net/baidoct/xtLekz08/6/  (The .switch should be the trigger and not whole .card)

Comment: I havent thought it through completely, however here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Matle/bnqd10ou/6/) to get you started - you can simply attach the event to the `.switch` class with `$('.switch').click(flipCard);`, get the text from the current target (span), get the parent node (first div above span), toggle whatever class you want, go to yet another, and yet another parent node, toggle classes etc. - hope helps you getting started

Answer (score 0):

Here I created an event listener on a parent element to the cards. No matter how many cards there are this event will be fired.
When you click either the header or one of the parent divs the nearest `<div class="card">` will be found. Now the class name can be toggled for that element.

```js
// event listener for any of the cards
document.getElementById('cardwrapper').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // what card was clicked
  let card = e.target.closest('.card');
  // toogle class name 'is-switched'
  card.classList.toggle('is-switched');
});
```

```css
$card-transition-time: 0.5s;
.card {
  perspective: 600px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card.is-switched .card__wrapper {
  animation: rotate .5s linear both;
}

.card__wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate-inverse .5s linear both;
}

.card__side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.card__side.is-active {
  position: static;
}

.card__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateY(200deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-inverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateY(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
}

// ignore
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.card__side {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff4136;
}

.card__side--back {
  background-color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardwrapper">
  <div class="card" id="item1">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__side is-active">
        <h1>Card 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card__side card__side--back">
        <h2>Card 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" id="item2">
    <div class="card__wrapper">
      <div class="card__side is-active">
        <h1>Card 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card__side card__side--back">
        <h2>Card 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```